# Two blocks are placed side by side on a surface (friction is present). What is the frictional force distribution between two blocks?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

Two blocks are placed as shown in the figure above.

Maximum possible friction between *5kg block* and surface is *5 * 10 * 0.5 = 25 N* (*10 m/s^2* is the acceleration due to gravity).

Maximum possible friction between 10kg block and surface is *10 * 10 * 0.5 = 50 N*.

The blocks are not going to move as maximum friction is *75N*. But what are the frictional forces on each block.

Friction on *5 kg block* is enough to oppose the *20N* force. So, **which of the following is correct?**

1. *friction on 5 kg = 20 N, friction on 10 kg = 0 N (5 kg block completely opposes the 20 N force)*
2. *friction on 5 kg = 20/3 N, friction on 10 kg = 40/3 N (distributed according to mass)*
3. *not possible to find the frictional force distribution.*

Also, **what is the friction distribution if *40 N* is applied on the *5 Kg block* instead of *20 N*?**

**edit**: Assume the simplistic situation, where there are no deformations and the friction is uniform on the surface.

Thanks.

Comment: @DKNguyen Made the questions bold. Using 10m/s^2 as acceleration of gravity so that it will be easy for those reading the question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a simplistic model (no deformation or microscopic movements, etc).

If the applied force is insufficient to overcome the force of friction of the first block, there is no applied force left over with which the first block can transfer to the next block. Therefore, the second block does not contribute to the static friction.

[image]

If the force applied is enough to overcome the static friction of the first block, but not the total static friction of two blocks then the first block "uses up" all of its friction force to oppose the applied force, at which point it is forced against the second block where the force of friction of the second block opposes the remainder of the applied force.

The force between the blocks is treated as an internal stress of the two-block system and is in equal and opposite directions.

[image]

Comment: Following this logic and dividing vertically each block in infinitesimal ones, the left elements must produce more friction force that the right ones, friction will be not uniform in the contact surface. In fact, your model results in a Heaviside friction function corresponding, from left to right, to elements with the maximal friction until a point where it falls to zero.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I don't disagree with that but that still doesn't change the friction force on the block as a whole.

Comment: @DKNguyen your answer and mine are exactly same , since it was a hw question i wanted the op to do the second part himself.

Comment: @Dirichlet Oh, it had not occurred to me it was homework. I thought it was more of a curiosity thing and mainly made this answer after be prompted by pasaba so we could talk about things.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Where is the discontinuity? I don't see a step in anything anywhere. If you consider that real objects do deform, then the parts nearest to the applied force actually do move and the infinitesmal sections on the left side of the first block actually do compress. But then we're getting into the stuff that sammy gerbil is talking about

Comment: @pasabaporaquip it is a simple classical mechanics question,  imho you are overcomplicating this .

Comment: @Dirichlet: friction is uniform in all surface contact if same pressure and material characteristics ( friction coefficient). Recall friction is due to interaction of body particles with surface ones, a process uniform in all surface. The model you present says that in a sequence of equal touching blocks, left ones will produce friction and right ones not. This is an error.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Actually, I think what you're saying is less accurate here. You're treating the entire object's contact area as one bulk area. But since real objects do deform, it is more accurate to treat them as infinitesmal areas that can move with respect to one another causing uneven distribution. So it is only an error in the sense it goes against the initial assumption of no deformation, but is more reflective of reality in that real objects do deform. I am increasingly certain that the 
"uniform friction distribution" thing is a macro-level approximation.

Comment: @Dirichlet This is not an assignment for me. I was teaching someone who is in 12th grade. The question was to find the contact force when the two blocks are moving. Just got curious what is frictional force distributing if the force applied is not sufficient to move the blocks.

Comment: @DKNguyen: please, note all my comments says "same friction if same pressure and material" (in the elemental surface). For a contact surface of area $A$ related to a body of weight $W$ (in Newtons) with uniform distribution, the pressure is $W/A$. The friction done by a differential element of area $ds$ is $c ( W/A ) ds$ and the total friction is $c ( W/A ) A = cW$, being $c$ the friction coefficient.

Comment: @sai Note that , for a question to be assignment type , it doesn't necessarily have to  be from an assignment  .

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Yes, however, with deformation the differential elements become more distinct with one another and with that movement the friction distribution would not be evenly distributed, just like it would not be evenly distributed between the two blocks. There's no real distinction, mathematically, between having two big blocks, or a bunch of tiny blocks (short of things like material differences which result in differences in coefficients of friction or deformation).

Comment: Let's put it this way: Lean lightly against a block if there is a block that weighs as much as you do, with the same footprint as you do, with the same material as the soles of your shoes. Are you telling me that if I push against the block near the base (so it doesn't tip over) just below the force of static friction for that block that you would expect to feel 1/2 force on your feet? Because that's what your answer says but that is clearly not what happens (unless you were leaning hard enough to preload things like sammy gerbil mentioned).

Comment: I have a force sensor at work and aluminum blocks. I could actually just do the test with the blocks butted up gently against the sensor, and then butted up harder so things are preloaded for the spring action between the two.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 3 is correct**. Without more information the distribution of friction force is **indeterminate**. It depends how this situation has been reached, and the exact model of static friction (which could be different for each block). Any combination of friction forces is possible (at least in theory) subject to the static limits given.

Whether the applied force is 20N or 40N the overall static limit is not reached, so there is no motion and the distribution of friction force is indeterminate. It is only when the overall static limit of 75N has been reached that the distribution of friction force is determinate (25N and 50N respectively).

---

One model is that static friction is generated from a microscopic elastic displacement, similar to Hooke's Law. (See **The Dahl Model** on p 6 of [A Study of Friction Models and Friction Compensation](http://www.mate.tue.nl/mate/pdfs/11194.pdf).) Using this model, suppose that the 5kg block has an elastic displacement of 25um before it starts moving when the applied force is 25N. ie It has a spring constant of 1N/um. And that the 10kg block also has a displacement of 25um before it starts moving when the applied force is 50N. ie It has a spring constant of 2N/um.

First place the blocks initially separated by 20um. Then the 20N applied force will move the 5kg block 20um bringing it into contact with the 10kg block. We are left with the 5kg block providing all of the friction and the 10kg block providing none. (Option 1.)

As a second scenario suppose the blocks are initially placed in contact. Friction is generated such that any displacements are the same for both blocks - ie **the blocks behave like springs in parallel**. The 20N friction force is distributed 6.7N from the 5kg block and 13.3N from the 10kg block. (Option 2.)

In another scenario a 20N pull to the right is applied on the 10kg block, sustained by a 10um elastic displacement to the right. Then the 5kg block is placed in contact with it on the left. It is not displaced so there is no friction force on it. Now a pushing force on the 5kg block is applied from the left, building up from zero to 20N, exactly as the pulling force is reduced to zero on the right. The 5kg block remains undisplaced bearing no friction force, while the 10kg block retains its 10um displacement and 20N friction force. (The converse of Option 1.)

More complicated scenarios could be imagined. It is even possible to arrange for the friction force on the 5kg block to point to the right, **in the same direction as the applied force**.

For example, start with a 50N pull to the right on the 10kg block. This creates 50N of static friction to the left. Then set the 5kg block in contact on the left. Gradually reduce the 50N pulling force to 20N. This generates a friction force of 10N to the right on the 5kg block while the friction on the 10kg block reduces to 30N to the left. Finally gradually reduce the pulling force on the right to zero while increasing a compensating pushing force to the right on the 5kg from zero up to 20N. We are left with friction forces 30N to the left on the 10kg block and 10N to the right on the 10kg block.

Other models of static friction also exist, such as mixed elastic-plastic deformations and 'creep' (ie relaxation, time-dependence). (See link above.)

Comment: How can the friction distribution be indeterminant in the 20N case when it cannot overcome the static friction of the 5kg block to transfer any force to the 10kg block? At 20N, the 10kg block essentially doesn't exist. By that logic, if I was leaning on a car and you shoved the car from the otherside, I would feel that shove despite the car not budging. We both know that's not the case.

Comment: @DKNguyen You are describing the 1st scenario in my answer. Your argument relies on the 5kg block not moving at all even on a microscopic level. However using the Dahl Model.there *are* microscopic movements. Your argument with the car also ignores microscopic movements. You cannot feel any transmitted force unless something displaces your skin. Sound in air and in solids is the result of vibrations (=movement) of a surface. If there is no movement of the surface then there is no sound.

Comment: I see. Yes, if that's how deeply you want to go from "ideal" scenario of questions.

Comment: @DKNguyen The question does not state what the "ideal" friction model is. In some countries/schools you are taught that one particular model is correct and all others are wrong, even when you have not been told what model to use. That is a bad way of learning IMO because it obscures the fact that the answer depends on the assumptions. Each of the 3 options is arguable.

Comment: "Ideal" was the wrong word. "Simplistic" is more what I meant. I would remove the downvote now that I understand the answer better, but it won't let me without an edit.

Answer (score 1):

First option is correct i.e

> friction on 5 kg = 20 N, friction on 10 kg = 0 N (5 kg block completely opposes the 20 N force

As long as the external force overcome the frictional force on the smaller block the contact force between the block will be 0.

In the second case , the blocks will not move as limiting value of static friction is greater than external force.

**Hint**

1. To find the frictional force i suggest you to draw the free body of diagram of both blocks and write equation of motion for each block , and then set up acceleration =0.
2. The normal reaction/ the contact force between the block is the frictional force on the bigger block. It will be very easy to see if you draw the free body diagram.

**Edit**

> Assume block of 5 kg is split in a stack of 5 blocks of 1 kg. According to this answer, what will do first of these 1kg blocks ? Its maximum static friction 5N ? Move ?

I believed that in newtonian mechanics,  every object is treated as point object rather than the mass is distributed along the surface .

Comment: I assume you are getting downvotes because you did not explain yourself clearly enough. I assume your reasoning is that the applied force of 20N is too small to overcome the maximum force of static friction of the 5kg block, therefore none of that force makes it through the 5kg to apply pressure to the 10kg block.

Comment: The second reason for the downvotes may be because you did not actually answer the OP's question about the 40N case. You just made an obvious comment about the scenario which the OP is already aware of.

Comment: @DKNguyen: I've downvoted this answer because no model supports it. Assume block of 5 kg is split in a stack of 5 blocks of 1 kg. According to this answer, what will do first of these 1kg blocks ? Its maximum static friction 5N ? Move ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui A stack? Stack typically means vertical. Do you mean horizontal?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I still don't see the issue. If the applied force cannot overcome the force of friction of the first block, then it cannot apply force to any of the blocks behind it so they contribute nothing to the static friction. If the applied force is great enough, the static friction force of the first block is overcome and that first block now applies force to the block behind it and that second block now contributes to the static friction. Still nothing moves unless the applied force is enough to overcome the static friction of all the block so force can be applied through all blocks.

Comment: Drawing free body diagrams of each block will show this.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Done........

Answer (score 0):

Could be some day of some millennium teachers start to draw surfaces not as perfect skating surfaces when talking about friction:

[image]

Assuming that the "past" history of the experiment has been:

1. place the two blocks over the surface and in contact between them.
2. apply the push force.

Then each micro-element (bump) of the horizontal surface produces a friction force against the push force, proportional to the pressure in this contact element.

At macro level, that means body of 5 kg will produce a friction $f_5=5a$ and body of 10 kg a friction $f_{10}=10a$, being the addition of both frictions equal to the push force of 20N.

$$f_5+f_{10}=5a+10a\underset{\cdot}{=} 20 N \rightarrow a = 4/3 N$$
$$f_5=5a=20/3 N$$
$$f_{10}=10a=40/3 N$$

Conclusion: b)

In case push force is 40N instead of 20N, friction forces are double.

Curiosity: this answer is valid even in other planets, $g \ne 9.8$, with the only condition maximal static friction is not surpassed.

Note1: Sammy Gerbil answer is very good and detailed, but it covers cases (except second one) that probably are out of the question. You can answer c), but then prepare to visit the teacher's office to defend your answer.

Note2: At atomic level we have not "bumps" but electromagnetic interactions, the "bump" similitude is only a teaching resource.

Comment: You are assuming the blocks are placed in contact before the 20N force is applied - this is not stated in the question. You are also assuming that the blocks are made of the same material - ie have the same friction model (force v micro displacement) - also not stated. ... Why are my cases "out of the question"? We are not told how the blocks got into the situation shown.... All answers need to be defended with arguments. ... The "bumps" model is only one possible model of friction.

Comment: @sammygerbil: at least we agree that, in the scenario I explicity clarified, the answer is "b)".

Comment: @sammygerbil: You can look for complex scenarios that made invalid the "b)" answer: blocks could be in a accelerating elevator; one of the blocks could have an initial speed; etc. However, if filling a test exam for a course where friction concept is explained, the expected answer is "b)", the one of the most simple scenario.

Comment: Options 1 & 2 are both simple and possible, but neither is necessarily correct. Whichever the expected answer for the test, all other answers are incorrect - this argument applies to all options. Physics SE is not a test, and we don't know what the examiner expected. The purpose of this site is to discuss what is correct physics, not to advise students how to pass tests..